# Smoothing Small Data Set With Second Order Quadratic Curve

Tags: c++, c, statistics, signal-processing, quadratic

I'm doing some specific signal analysis, and I am in need of a method that would smooth out a given bell-shaped distribution curve. A running average approach isn't producing the results I desire. I want to keep the min/max, and general shape of my fitted curve intact, but resolve the inconsistencies in sampling.

In short: if given a set of data that models a simple quadratic curve, what statistical smoothing method would you recommend?

If possible, please reference an implementation, library, or framework.

Thanks SO!

**Edit**: Some helpful data

(A possible signal graph)

[image]

The dark colored quadratic is my "fitted" curve of the light colored connected data points.

The sample @ -44 (approx.), is a problem in my graph (i.e. a potential sample inconsistency). I need this curve to "fit" the distribution better, and overcome the values that do not trend accordingly. Hope this helps!

Comment: By "inconsistencies in sampling," do you mean that the sampling rate was variable or are you referring to signal noise?

Comment: @Judge Maygarden - I added a possible graph of where a value trends away from the curve dramatically.

Comment: You need to describe your data better.  Is this a distribution, time-series, or what?  Do you want to fit a quadratic function, or something more flexible? The best model will depend on how your data is generated.  Given a model class, there are various approaches to estimation.

Comment: @Tristen, I do want to fit a quadratic function (hence the title). It's a collection of small readings over time (3-10avg). This should be enough information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "quadratic" curve is one thing; "bell-shaped" usually means a Gaussian normal distribution.  Getting a best-estimate Gaussian couldn't be easier: you compute the sample mean and variance and your smooth approximation is

```
y = exp(-squared(x-mean)/variance)
```

If, on the other hand, you want to approximate a smooth curve with a quadradatic, I'd recommend computing a quadratic polynomial with minimum square error.  I can nenver remember the formulas for this, but if you've had differential calculus, write the formula for the total square error (pointwise) and differentiate with respect to the coefficients of your quadratic.  Set the first derivatives to zero and solve for the best approximation.  Or you could look it up.

Finally, if you just want a smooth-looking curve to approximate a set of points, [cubic splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) are your best bet.  The curves won't necessarily mean anything, but you'll get a nice smooth approximation.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

struct WeightedData 
{
double x;
double y;
double weight;
};

void findQuadraticFactors(WeightedData *data, double &a, double &b, double &c, unsigned int const datasize)
{
double w1 = 0.0;
double wx = 0.0, wx2 = 0.0, wx3 = 0.0, wx4 = 0.0;
double wy = 0.0, wyx = 0.0, wyx2 = 0.0;
double tmpx, tmpy;
double den;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < datasize; ++i) 
    {
    double x = data[i].x;
    double y = data[i].y;
    double w = data[i].weight;  

    w1 += w;
    tmpx = w * x;
    wx += tmpx;
    tmpx *= x;
    wx2 += tmpx;
    tmpx *= x;
    wx3 += tmpx;
    tmpx *= x;
    wx4 += tmpx;
    tmpy = w * y;
    wy += tmpy;
    tmpy *= x;
    wyx += tmpy;
    tmpy *= x;
    wyx2 += tmpy;
    }

den = wx2 * wx2 * wx2 - 2.0 * wx3 * wx2 * wx + wx4 * wx * wx + wx3 * wx3 * w1 - wx4 * wx2 * w1;
if (den == 0.0) 
    {
    a = 0.0;
    b = 0.0;
    c = 0.0;
    }
else    
    {
    a = (wx * wx * wyx2 - wx2 * w1 * wyx2 - wx2 * wx * wyx + wx3 * w1 * wyx + wx2 * wx2 * wy - wx3 * wx * wy) / den;
    b = (-wx2 * wx * wyx2 + wx3 * w1 * wyx2 + wx2 * wx2 * wyx - wx4 * w1 * wyx - wx3 * wx2 * wy + wx4 * wx * wy) / den;
    c = (wx2 * wx2 * wyx2 - wx3 * wx * wyx2 - wx3 * wx2 * wyx + wx4 * wx * wyx + wx3 * wx3 * wy - wx4 * wx2 * wy) / den;
    }

}

double findY(double const a, double const b, double const c, double const x)
{       
return a * x * x + b * x + c; 
};




int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
WeightedData data[9];
data[0].weight=1; data[0].x=1; data[0].y=-52.0; 
data[1].weight=1; data[1].x=2; data[1].y=-48.0; 
data[2].weight=1; data[2].x=3; data[2].y=-43.0; 
data[3].weight=1; data[3].x=4; data[3].y=-44.0; 
data[4].weight=1; data[4].x=5; data[4].y=-35.0; 
data[5].weight=1; data[5].x=6; data[5].y=-31.0; 
data[6].weight=1; data[6].x=7; data[6].y=-32.0; 
data[7].weight=1; data[7].x=8; data[7].y=-43.0; 
data[8].weight=1; data[8].x=9; data[8].y=-52.0; 

double a=0.0, b=0.0, c=0.0;
findQuadraticFactors(data, a, b, c, 9);
std::cout << " x \t y" << std::endl;
for (int i=0; i<9; ++i)
    {
    std::cout << " " << data[i].x << ", " << findY(a,b,c,data[i].x) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the parameters for your running average are set wrong (sample window too small or large)?

Is it just noise superimposed on your bell curve? How close is the noise frequency to that of the signal you're trying to retrieve? A picture of what you're trying to extract might help us identify a solution.

You could try some sort of fitting algorithm using a [least squares fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares) if you can make a reasonable guess of the function parameters. Those sorts of techniques often have some immunity to noise.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple digital [low-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter)?

```
y[0] = x[0];
for (i = 1; i < len; ++i)
    y[i] = a * x[i] + (1.0 - a) * y[i - 1];
```

In this case, **x[]** is your input data and **y[]** is the filtered output. The **a** coefficient is a value between 0 and 1 that you should tweak. An **a** value of 1 reproduces the input and the [cut-off frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency) decreases as **a** approaches 0.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but the problem with this approach is by the time the coefficient is low enough to "fix" the discrepancies, the shape changes a lot and the min/max fit becomes inaccurate.

Comment: If that's the case, then you would need to increase the sampling rate for this approach to work. Is that an option?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not. In my case, an average sample cluster would be 3 to 10.