# Polynomial fit with minima/maxima constraint

Tags: c, polynomial-math, quadratic

I have noisy data that should fit a quadratic function. Specifically:

1. The data should fit a portion of a parabola
2. The parabola may open either up or down
3. The peak is guaranteed to not be within the dataset
4. The peak is guaranteed to be in a known direction from the dataset
5. The distance from my dataset to the peak is not known

In essence, I know I am somewhere on the side of parabola, but not exactly where, nor do I know the shape of the parabola. That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Currently I am using this approach to solve for the polynomial: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7001353/25704
This does a very good job, but it often solves for the peak of the parabola to be within my dataset.  I've had no luck finding an algorithm that would avoid that situation.

The only solution I've thought of so far is to mirror the data I have on the opposite side of the parabola and fit that as well. However, this would require that I know the distance to the peak.

Does anyone know of a technique where I can push the peak to where I want it without ruining the fit?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if the link you provided implements a standard quadratic regression, but have you tried that? The regression shouldn't be predisposed to forcing the peak in the middle of the data somewhere unless that's what really gives the least squares fit. In that case, if you're trying to avoid what the least squares fit is really telling you, then you're looking for a way to skew that?

Comment: I'm trying to correct a low frequency bias in a signal that may include high frequency data... That "noise" fools the algorithm into thinking the peak is within the data.

Comment: I see. Then the first thing that comes to mind is to run it through a digital filter first, then do the regression.